# How Do I Generate A Random _Id for MongoDB In Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

On MongoDB the _Id field for some reason is always very similar, so similar that after 20 documents I cant insert more because the _Id will be the same. What I think is happening is MongoDB generates the _Id based on what's inside the document and all of the documents I inserted is very similar (but not the same). What I wanted to do for this is generating a random _Id to get around this.

What I tried first was randomly picking litters and numbers from a list 24 times (because the _Id field is 24 characters long), this is how I did that:

```py
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
key = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(24))
```

But that gave me a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Is there any other way to generate a random _Id?

Comment: _"On MongoDB the _Id field for some reason is always very similar, so similar that after 20 documents I cant insert more because the _Id will be the same."_  Are you generating `"_id"`?  I've inserted 10s of millions of documents without specifying `"_id"` and have not experienced that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The **secrets.choice()** function is used to select a single random element from a sequence (like a list or a string), but you're trying to apply it to a slice (a part of a sequence). To generate a random string of a specific length using the characters from alphabet, you can modify your code like this:

```
import string
import secrets

alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
key = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(24))
print(key)
```

Here, `for _ in range(24)` iterates **24 times**, and in each iteration, a random character from alphabet is selected and added to the key string.

Comment: I still got a TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: @Mac.exe if you try to print alphabet after doing alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits how is it valued?

Comment: what do you mean by valued?

Comment: @Mac.exe print(alphabet) what does it return?

Comment: Oh I get It, It's abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

Comment: very strange. what version of python are you using?

Comment: It's Python 3.11

Comment: very strange, in my case key = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(24)) is valued as SanjDfJ8Wcd8mY9fg85b0IuF

Comment: I reinstalled python but now I got bson.errors.InvalidId: 'hXkC1Hw29DPuF7JqSB0zNqFm' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB and its associated drivers and tools always ensure that the automatically created `_id` field is unique to the current database. For all reasonable purposes you can extend the statement to say the generated `_id`s are globally unique.

If you create them in quick succession they will look similar; that's because they are made up of a random machine identifier, add the current date. crucially though there is always an incrementing 3-byte counter. So unless you are adding more than 16 million records a seconds, you won't run into any duplicates.

Comment: For some reason even in the matter of days my _ids are usually only 1 character different

Comment: The date is stored in the first 6 characters; you should see these change every second.